# wp_add_inline_style breaking style and not working

Tags: css

i have an option field where i save custom style and use `wp_add_inline_style` to output. But it does not work as expected. Suppose i have `.fep-some-class > div` but if i see source code of my page i see `.fep-some-class &gt; div`. that means it is encoding. why and how to overcome this? Also in codex page https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style it is stated that i have to sanitize. What will be better way to sanitize css?

EDIT:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin-style', plugins_url() . 'my-plugin/style.css' );

$custom_css = trim( get_option('my-plugin-custom-css') );
if( $custom_css ) {
    wp_add_inline_style( 'my-plugin-style', $custom_css );
}
```

as custom css if i add `.fep-some-class > div { display:none }` it does not have any effect. if i view my page source code i see `.fep-some-class &gt; div { display:none }`

EDIT:

thanks @majick
it was the case when saving. See bellow scenario

my form was like this

```
<form method="post" action="MY-PLUGIN-OPTIONS-PAGE">
<textarea name="name"><?php echo esc_textarea( $field['value' ] ); ?></textarea>
.........
....... //other fields
</form>
```

I did not have any sanitize filter for this when saving. So when first time write code and save. It works perfectly. But if go to option page again and change some other fields and save. it save already encoded value by `esc_textarea` . so now i change `esc_textarea` to `wp_kses_post` that should works

Comment: add your code or we have no chance of helping you

Comment: I think the problem is how the CSS is being saved (via a sanitization filter?) rather than output, to test you can change to `$custom_css = trim( html_entity_decode ( 'my-plugin-custom-css') );` ... if that works it would likely confirm the HTML encoding is being done upon saving.

Comment: please post the solution as an answer and accept it ;)

Comment: is it ok to use `wp_kses_post` upon saving only? codex page said i have to sanitize custom css, should i use more sanitize when using `wp_add_inline_style` @mark-kaplun ?

Comment: well, kses is used to sanotize html and you are talking about html here. The easiest thing is to prevent anyone except from admin to modify the style and then you can skip sanitization. In a mutisite you should just not give the option at all. What I would suggest is to take a look at the jetpack code as they have some css input functionality and they probably put more effort into doing it right. Side note: I always find this kind of features problematic because it means that users need to learn CSS to properly use it, an if they are so technically advanced they better create child theme

Comment: and just add whatever css rules they want in the code

Comment: maybe you should just sanitize with `strip_tags()`